# Can't connect to a Wi-Fi network

Tags: windows-10-mobile, wifi

My phone is on Windows 10 Mobile, build 10586.242. I can't connect to my home wifi network whereas other devices can. I've tried forgetting the network and reconnecting, but my phone says "unable to connect". How can I fix this?

This has been a frequent problem with Windows 10 Mobile! There are previous questions asked here based on this but all were WP 8.1 related.

Comment: Have you tried a soft reset? (Power+VolumeDown)

Comment: yup, i did, problem is that, it sometimes connects, sometimes it doesnt!

Comment: Please refrain from reverting constructive edits that improve the formatting, grammar or readability of your post. Note that Stack Exchange sites are collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. For more information, see [this article in our Help Center](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what type of WiFi network it is and what authentication is being used?

Comment: What phone do you have and are you on any of the Insider Preview rings?

Comment: I had this same problem, but here is the strange thing...I downloaded field medic, and it said that it was connected to wifi, even though the network connections said it wasn't and refused to "connect". So I got on my router pulled up the DHCP Client list and sure enough there was my phone and a IP address... successful ping...then after about 2 weeks it just all of a sudden started working...No explanation...No answer...and I haven't had a problem since...

Comment: i just resetted my phone, my phone 520 with build 10586.242. Now its connecting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your home WiFi set to use as authentication? If it is using one of the older formats, you won't be able to connect. MSFT could really improve the error messages but Windows 10 Mobile has issues with the old TKIP standard.

So: set your router to use WPA2 AES and on the device:

Wireless Setting > Manually > WPA > Cipher Type > AES

One other thing that also helped in some cases was to switch from 5GHz to 2.4

Comment: its already on wpa2 aes setting. my phone didnt connect with network yesterday, when i tried just now, its getting connected. dunno if it connects after sometime. this problem has been troubling me since i reset my phone 2 weeks back.